# mySolutionName.exe file deleted from /debug directory. How to restore or rebuild?

Tags: c#

I'm new to c#. Antivirus deleted the mySolutionName.exe file out of the /debug directory and now I cannot execute my code. I'm concerned that anything I do may make the issue worse.

When I press F5 I get an error of:

> CS2012  C# Cannot open for writing --> C:\Users\me\source\repos\MyApp\MyApp\obj\Debug\MyApp.exe''

Can someone please tell me how to rebuild the file so that I can continue developing?

Comment: should be bulit every time you hit the built button but if your antivirus is blocking it you might consider whitlisting it or disabling atnivir temporarily

Comment: Firstly you need to work out if there is a legitimate virus you are distributing, then if you are satisfied its a false positive, just exclude that directory in the virus scanner

Comment: Are you sure the antivirus deleted it? "Cannot open for writing" can happen under other circumstances

Comment: I did whitlist the entire directory, but, when I hit F5 it says that "access to the path is denied"

Comment: I've used AV software like you are describing before. It interprets the writing to an Executable file as a Virus action, which in your case would be a false positive. The AV product had an option to exclude certain directories from the AV scan. I ended up restructuring my projects so they all fell in the same root folder and then excluded that.

Comment: you can also try running visual studio as administrator or delete the entire debug folder (it will be rebuilt and this will ensurte noone is still reading any of oyur files)

Comment: if all else fails turn your pc off and on again :)

Answer (score 2):

after your edit:

Your program is probably still running outside of the debugger.
You need to use the task-manageer to kill all instances of `MyApp.exe` if this doesnt solve your issue a reboot should do the trick as well

So why is this happening?
Most liky your application is somewhere stuck on a blocking function or in a never ending loop. maybe there is even a seperate thread still operating that you forgot to close. We lack some information to tell yout that for sure. But to find out what is happening you can close your window while running in debugger mode and see if the application properly closes. if it doesnt you can hit pause and see where the program is stuck and resolve this issue by ending the task/loop/whatever in your OnClosing function of your window.

Comment: Rebuild did not work, same problem. Going to try a reboot now.

Comment: @Fildor added it for your pleasure :)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/56833215/480982 to find out which program accesses the file if it's not the application itself. Might prevent you from rebooting.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to solve this issue is looking which process currently accesses the file.

A tool to do that is [Microsoft SysInternals Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer). It has a feature called "Find handle or DLL ..." which can be accessed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

The result will show the process which accesses the file. You can then judge whether it's Antivirus or something else that prevents you from writing to the file. If possible, you can then take an action in that program to release the file.

Example: a program is accessing my powerpoint presentation, which has the term "Schulungen" in its file name.

[image: Screenshot]

Process Explorer figures out: it's open in Powerpoint.exe, so I can simply close the file in Powerpoint - problem fixed.